# Addition of 1 new column in 6 tables has increased MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, cakephp

We recently added a new column to six different tables in our database and now most of our web pages are very slow to load. Investigation shows that the number of MySQL queries has greatly increased even though there was only a small change to the code. For example, one page now shows approximately 4,000 queries compared to 800 before.

The same changes to the database were made on the pre-production server's database without any problem.

The host's profiling tool show these queries as 'mysql_query'.

We are at a loss as to why this has happened. Is there anything we need to do within CakePHP after adding new fields to the database? Any ideas what could be the problem?

Edit: One thought I had was that somehow the queries were being repeated and hence the large number of queries appearing in the profiling tool.

Comment: if the column is used to join tables (i.e. user_id) this could be normal. What column did you add?

Comment: @arilia - It wasn't a column used to join tables. Just a small int column to hold a count. Could it have affected the joins of the tables somehow? I'm by no means a MySQL expert.

Comment: is it used for counterCache? I think that counterCache count items before every save/delete/update

Comment: @arilia - No, it's not used for counterCache. The confusing thing is why we're having the problem on one server and not another.

Comment: Normally 800 queries to show one page? This looks terribly wrong already. If you can explain the reasoning behind that excessive DB use perhaps it might be a pointer to what is wrong.

Comment: Try to use contain or unbind model.. so that unwanted queries will reduce